# How to get the selected text of webview in ActionMode override

Tags: android, webview, actionmode

I am adding some custom menu items in the Contextual Action Menu. I need to give a web search feature with the words selected in the WebView.

I override the ActionMode using this code.

```
@Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if (mActionMode == null) {
                mActionMode = mode;
            Menu menu = mode.getMenu();

            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        }
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}


public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_search:
            //HERE I WANT TO GET THE TEXT: HOW CAN I?
            break;
    }

    if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
}
```

I want to search my site using the word selected by the user in the webview, but I couln't get the way to get the selected text. How could i get that, any one please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With Android API >= 19 you can use `webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()", new ValueCallback<String>()
          {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String value)
            {
              Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
}});` On older builds your only resort is a custom javascript interface with a single method accepting `String`, which you should call via `webview.loadUrl` passing the same thing (`js.callback(window.getSelection().toString())`).

Comment: @Stan can you please put it as a code in an answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only way to get text selection from a `WebView` is based on javascript. This is not specific to the action mode, this is how `WebView` text selection is supposed to be retrieved according to `WebView` developers' point of view. They deliberately decided to not provide an API to access text selection from Java.

The solution comprise 2 approaches.

With Android API >= 19 you can use `evaluateJavascript`:

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
new ValueCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
    }
});
```

On older builds your only resort is a custom javascript interface with a single method accepting `String`, which you should call via `webview.loadUrl` passing the same thing:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:js.callback(window.getSelection().toString())");
```

where `js` is the attached javascript interface:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "js");
```

and

```
public class WebAppInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void callback(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks a lot for saving my life :-)

Comment: The first method (evaluateJavascript) did not work for me. Am I doing something wrong? I'm getting an empty string for value in onRecieveValue method.

Comment: @clu Try on different web-pages (best is your own test web page), make sure, a selection does exist. Add some logging to javascript part.

Comment: For very first time i'm getting null value from this method 
==========================================================================================================

webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
new ValueCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
    }
});
==========================================================================================================