# Android Webview : How to copy selected text in webview.

Tags: android, sqlite, webview, selection, contextual-action-bar

I am new in android development, I am create an apps to store selected webview content into sqlite database. When user select of word, custom contextual action bar will display in webview. And now I need to get selected word in WebView. Any idea on how to get selected word in WebView and return as String?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get text selection from a `WebView` is based on javascript. This is not specific to the action mode, this is how `WebView` text selection is supposed to be retrieved according to `WebView` developers' point of view. They deliberately decided to not provide an API to access text selection from Java.

The solution comprise 2 approaches.

With Android `API >= 19` you can use `evaluateJavascript`:

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
new ValueCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
    }
});
```

On older builds your only resort is a custom javascript interface with a single method accepting String, which you should call via `webview.loadUrl` passing the same thing:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:js.callback(window.getSelection().toString())");
```

where `js` is the attached javascript interface:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "js");
```

and

```
public class WebAppInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void callback(String value)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
    }
}

Reference:
```

[How to get the selected text of webview in ActionMode override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804100/how-to-get-the-selected-text-of-webview-in-actionmode-override)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use the same method   webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()" before. But when I debug and the String value return null.

Comment: @JackChan have you tested with API>=19 check?

Comment: yaya, I tested with API 22. I debug and get value of String value. It is null value

Comment: Thanks a lot. problem Solved.

Comment: @JackChan If this answer helped you can accept the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @ChanYoongHon Can you please tell how did you solve the problem? In my case also, it is returning null