# Android - fail to call default paste method

Tags: android, clipboard, paste

I made custom contextual action bar in Webview.

And there are copy and paste buttons.

Copy action is working with ClipboardManager.

But pasting method doesn't work.

I referenced this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html#PastePlainText) and problem with setting enabled.

```
MenuItem mPasteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_paste);
if (!(clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())) {
  mPasteItem.setEnabled(false);
} else if (!(clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))) {        
    mPasteItem.setEnabled(false);
} else {        
    mPasteItem.setEnabled(true);
}
```

If I pass setEnabled method, there is no response even "if (pasteData != null) {
    return;}" called.

Any idea to work this?

---

**EDIT**
I checked with debug mode, my menu item of pasting operation is setenabled default.

So I think this process(setting enabled) is not necessary.

But Still, paste operation after return; called like below.

```
pasteData = item.getText();

if (pasteData != null) {
   return;
```

What is the problem?

Comment: question is not clear bro.you want to paste a copied string to an edit text, isnt it?

Comment: Yes but EditText can be in webview which is not declared by me. It means I can't control these EditTexts. So editText.setText() method is not helpful for me.

Comment: Then you have to rely on android paste method, and then you couldn't clear all Action Mode buttons :-)

Comment: Can you paste the action mode code so that a way could be found

Comment: public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        if (mActionMode == null) {
            mActionMode = mode;
            Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
            MenuItem pastedMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_paste);
            try {
                pastedMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception ex1) {                
                ex1.printStackTrace();
            }
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        }

Comment: This is my part of code. As a result, line "pastedMenuItem.setEnabled(true);" is not worked. (go to catch expression)

Comment: remove the above code and try whether the default paste method is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106937/discussion-between-devtest-and-jehyun-shim).

Comment: Sorry for no response. I tried more and found out that my menuitem is set enabled default(in debug mode). I think It means I don't have to call setEnabled(true). But stiil, after line passed "return;" pasting action is not worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150218/android-default-paste-operation-programmatically I added similar question.